# ActiveRecord: How to order by weighted average of associated through model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models,

```
    #user.rb
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :pictures
       has_many :ratings, dependent:  :destroy
       has_many :rated_pictures, through: :ratings, source: :picture
    end

    #picture.rb    
    class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
       #id, image, :user_id
       has_many :ratings, dependent:  :destroy
       has_many :rated_users, through: :ratings, source: :user

       def weighted_average
          data = ratings.group("stars").count
          w_sum = 0
          data.each{ |key, value| w_sum += key * value }
          (w_sum.to_f/data.values.sum).round(2)
       end
    end

    #rating.rb
    class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
      #id, user_id, picture_id and stars
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :picture
    end
```

User can rate other user's picture out of 5, I am calculating average(weighted average) of a picture using the function **picture.weighted_average**.

```
# To can get a user's pictures 
user = User.find_by_email 'abc@sample.com'
pictures = user.pictures
```

My query is how to order a user pictures by weighted_average using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

With [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort) function.

```
user.pictures.sort { |p1, p2| p1.weighted_average <=> p2.weighted_average }
```

Comment: More succinctly, `user.pictures.sort_by(&:weighted_average)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this via ActiveRecord (that is, in the database), as the `weighted_average` function is defined in your Ruby code. The best you can do is retrieve all the objects from the database, unsorted, and then sort them:

```
user.pictures.sort_by(&:weighted_average)
```

Comment: Okay, its working, but this make an extra query to find weighted_average on each picture record    **(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, stars AS stars FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."picture_master_id" = $1 GROUP BY stars  [["picture_master_id", 145]]** . I planning to add column weighted_average to Picture table to store value, update this value every time on rating creation.  Put your thought on this.